# Sequence number in a midi file. How does it work?

Tags: midi

I have been googling about it for a while but all the info I found was a little ambiguous. I'm not an expert in midi, I'm only interested in midi files. I need to know what this meta-event is for, and how it affects the playback of a multi-track midi file (format 1).

Answer (score 2):

For type 1 and type 2 MIDI files, the sequence number indicates that events for the given track will follow this event. If you are only interested in parsing type 1 files, this basically indicates the start of actual MIDI events. However, type 2 files may have several tracks, each one starting with a sequence meta event.

For more information, see: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/midifile/seq.htm

Comment: -1: The Sequence Number **does not** indicate "the start of actual MIDI events", it's just an optional ID number that applies to the entire song (aka "sequence"). Note: MIDI events are everything that's not a meta event. (MIDI events are sent out on a MIDI cable. Meta events are additional information in the MIDI file that can't be sent out on a MIDI cable.) Imagine if a MIDI file program stops scanning for a track name once it encounters a MIDI event in the track. Because of that possibility, you should put meta events that apply to the entire track at time zero and before MIDI events.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is the Sequence Number is just an additional piece of information that may be used  to identify a song. I think of it as a numerical alternative or supplement to the Sequence Name.

Imagine a drum box that can save or load its drum patterns into individual MIDI files (or perhaps into individual tracks in a single Format 2 MIDI file). Or imagine an electronic keyboard that can save or load its accompaniment patterns into individual MIDI files. In a scenario like this, I imagine the Sequence Number could be used to indicate which pattern number or accompaniment number the MIDI file (or Format 2 track) corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

"Sequence Number" is an ill conceived notion in MIDI files that's never been clearly implemented.  For a single file of type 0 or type 1, it has no meaning whatsoever.  It's a no-op.

For a file of type 2, or a collection of type 0 or type 1 files, it's intended to identify separate sequences, in order, like a sort of play list.  Players could then select a sequence by number.

If the sequence number isn't specified, it's assigned sequentially, although, again, for a single file this pretty much only matters for type 2.

In effect, sequence number has never really been used much to my knowledge.  Maybe in embedded applications like games...